# Python Combine 2 XLSX files

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv

I have two XLSX files which I need to combine. They are both Excel 2010 files (.xlsx) which what what I've read is space delimited (I'm open to correction). Both files will have the same number of rows and the rows will line up; e.g. row1,file1 will correspond to row1,file 2 etc... The files have very long fields so I'm just going to show mock data for simplicity. The first file has the format:

```
a 123 20 20141201
b 456 50 20141130
 .....
```

The second file has the format:

```
20141201
20141130
...
```

Therefore I would like the output to be:

```
a 123 20 20141201 20141201
b 456 50 20141130 20141130
...
```

My code is below, however there seems to be 2 problems:

Firstly, the output from array3 is not in the correct format:

```
'a 123 20 20141201 \t\r\n', '20141201\n',
'b 456 50 20141130 \t\r\n', '20141130\n', 
....
```

How can I concatenate these properly to ensure the other datestamp is before the tab, newline etc... (\t\r\n)?

Secondly, when I write this array to the output file the rows are inconsistent:

The first row has everything in 1 column separated by (note ☺ = white square symbol, not sure why it is appearing as a smiley face?):

```
     col1                                  col2     col3     col4       col5
row1|a ☺ 123 ☺ 20 ☺ 20141201 ☺☺ 20141201

row2|b                                     456      50       20141130

row3|20141130    

row4|c .........................
```

My code is here:

```
ins1 = open( "file1.xlsx", "r" )
array1 = []
for line in ins1:
    array1.append(line)
ins1.close()

ins2 = open( "file2.xlsx", "r" )
array2 = []
for line in ins2:
    array2.append(line)
ins2.close()  

array3 = []
for i in range(0, len(array1)):
    array3.append(array1[i])
    array3.append(array2[i])

resultFile = open("output.xlsx",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
print array3
wr.writerow(array3)
resultFile.close()
```

Apologies, I'm very new to Python so perhaps the above isn't the best approach to take. I'm open to alternative suggestions on how to go about this. I have had a look at Pandas which I believe would make this task much easier, unfortunately however I am unable to install outside libraries which rules out that option. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Based on Serge's answer here is a solution which works:

```
ins1 = open( "file1.xlsx", "r" )
ins2 = open( "file2.xlsx", "r" )
outs = open("output.xlsx",'wb')
for line in ins1:
    line = line.rstrip() + "\t" + next(ins2)
    print line.rstrip()
    outs.write(line)
ins1.close()
ins2.close()
outs.close()
```

Comment: "I have two CSVs which I need to combine. They are both Excel 2010 files (.xlsx) ..."  CSV and xlsx are different formats.  Which do you have?  Please edit your question and title to clarify.

Comment: Are these files guaranteed to be 'lined up' correctly with each other?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4371163/202168

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Sorry they are XLSX files. Question has been edited accordingly

Comment: @oobivat Yes the files will line up; row1,file1 will correspond to row1,file2 etc...

Comment: @JohnKilo : Can you really read xlsx file with that code `ins1 = open( "file1.xlsx", "r" )
array1 = []
for line in ins1:
    array1.append(line)
ins1.close()` ????? AFAIK xlsx is a **binary** format !

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm not sure, all I can tell you is that
`codeins1 = open( "file1.xlsx", "r" ) array1 = [] for line in ins1:array1.append(line) ins1.close()`
is working. I tried using code`open( "file1.xlsx", "rb" )` and I got the same output

Comment: So your files are not in xlsx format but are true CSV files. Can you open them with a simple text editor as notepad on Windows or vi on Linux to confirm ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. The fields seem to be tab delimited when I opened them up in Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your files are in csv format separated with spaces, the following simplified code should be enough :

```
with open( "file1.xlsx", "r" ) as ins1, open( "file2.xlsx", "r" ) as ins2, \
        open("output.xlsx",'wb') as resultfile :
    for line in ins1:
        line = line.rstrip() + " " + next(ins2)
        print line.rstrip()
        resultfile.write(line)
```

Explanation :

- `with` ensures the files are properly closed whatever can happen in code
- the above code processes the files line by line **assuming file1 and file2 are aligned**
- the code simply removes end of line from line from file1, and a space and the line from file2 and write the result to `output`
- the rstrip in print line avoids an extra new line

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Serge, I am getting a invalid syntax error in relation to the comma : `code  as ins1, open( "file2... ` after ins1 however. I'm using Python 2.6.4 for the record, I'm not sure if the error is related to this? Unfortunately this is the version I am stuck using.

Comment: @JohnKilo : the multiple with in same line is effectively a 2.7+ feature. I edited my post also using tab as separator

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the code and got the output file to generate. The last column is incorrect however; it contains both datestamps `code 17/11/2014 09:11:37 2014-11-17 09:11:06
` how can I get these to appear in different columns?

Comment: @JohnKilo I'm not sure to understand : are those 2 fields already present in file2 and are they separated in file2 ?

Comment: No those 2 fields are not already present. Currently file1 contains 4 fields including a datestamp, file2 contains only 1 field which is a datestamp. I'm trying to combine the 2 files so the output file has 5 columns including the timestamps from file1 and file2 respectively, in different columns.

Comment: I've figured it out. Thanks again for your help Serge. I will edit the question and include the answer in case any one else runs into the same problem!